# javascript: querySelector containing @ symbol is invalid

Tags: javascript, classname, queryselector

I have an element with a **className containing an @ symbol.**
Such as `<div class="modify@s">`

I can easily style this via a css selctor such as `.modify\@s`

But I can't use this selector to target the element via querySelector in javascript.

```
document.querySelector('.modify@s') 
document.querySelector('.modify\@s')
```

> '... is not a valid selector"

**How can I select this element by its specify className?**'

Below a demo to play around with presenting the issue.

```css
// this could be wrapped in a media query, so the @s reflects the mediaquery
.modify\@s {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="baseClass">BaseClass nothing special here</div>
<div class="baseClass modify@s">Modify with background</div>

<button onclick="document.querySelector('.modify@s').style.border = '3px solid blue';">select modify element and add border (causes error in console)</button>
 <button onclick="document.querySelector('.modify\@s').style.border = '3px solid blue';">select modify element (with escaped @) and add border  (causes error in console)</button>
```

Comment: Do a `console.log('.modify\@s')`, and tell me what you notice ...

Comment: Try `.modify\\@s` because \ is escape character so to get it in your string you need to escape it by using \\

Comment: `'.modify\@s'` -> `'.modify\\@s'`

Comment: `document.querySelector(".modify\\@s")` does work thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@` is valid in a class name but needs to be escaped in CSS (I presume that's to avoid clashes with [at-rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule)). But it turns out the escape symbol used by CSS (`\`) is the same as the escape symbol used by JavaScript. That means you need to escape it twice.

```css
// this could be wrapped in a media query, so the @s reflects the mediaquery
.modify\@s {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="baseClass">BaseClass nothing special here</div>
<div class="baseClass modify@s">Modify with background</div>

<button onclick="document.querySelector('.modify\\@s').style.border = '3px solid blue';">select modify element and add border (no longer causes error in console)</button>
```

Comment: I understand this answer is most likely a duplicate but I couldn't find it. So if you find it just link the question and I'll remove mine.